# Dealing with error "record or row variable cannot be part of multiple-item INTO list"

Tags: plpgsql

Is there a "cleaner" syntax for this "workaround"?

I have the following objects to work with:

```
create type token as(tp varchar(20), val varchar(128));
create or replace
function p_post_token
         (      token_type varchar,
         ,inout token_new  token
         ,inout tokens_all token[]
         ,  out b1         boolean
         ,  out b2         boolean
         ,  out b3         boolean
         ) as...
```

The function has some (long) logic, but ultimately it is:

1. modifying "new" record based on some conditions,
2. adding the "new" record to the "all" array,
3. null-ing out the "new" record, and
4. setting some booleans for output.

When I call my function as follows (a translation from Oracle PL/SQL):

```
do $$
declare
  lb1 boolean;
  lb2 boolean;
  lb3 boolean;
  --
  lr_token  token;
  lt_tokens token[];
begin
  select * into lr_token, lt_tokens, lb1, lb2, lb3
    from p_post_token('', lr_token, lt_tokens);
end$$;
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  record or row variable cannot be part of multiple-item INTO list
LINE 10:       select * into lr_token, lt_tokens, lb1, lb2, lb3
```

The workaround I was suggested is this:

```
do $$
declare
  lb1 boolean;
  lb2 boolean;
  lb3 boolean;
  --
  lr_token  token;
  lt_tokens token[];
  --
  r record;
begin
  select * into r
    from p_post_token('', lr_token, lt_tokens);
  lr_token  := r.token_new;
  lt_tokens := r.tokens_all;
  lb1       := r.b1;
  lb2       := r.b2;
  lb3       := r.b3;
end$$;
```

**This works**, but I have to call function p_post_token in a **dozen** places, and code like this, well, is "too long".

Is that the only way to read output from a function with INOUT/OUT record parameter(s) + other INOUT/OUT parameters? Is there (hopefully) a "one-liner" approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine suggested a (IMHO) much easier/better workaround. Turn the record parameter into an array. The function declaration will become:

```
function p_post_token
     (      token_type varchar
     ,inout token_new  token[] --<< this turned from record to array
     ,inout tokens_all token[]
     ,  out b1         boolean
     ,  out b2         boolean
     ,  out b3         boolean
     ) as...
```

... and let the code (internally) process only one record from the array.
This avoids a lot of "extra" code when dealing with a record.

The call to the function then becomes a one-liner (straightforward and intuitive, again IMHO):

```
do $$
declare
  lb1 boolean;
  lb2 boolean;
  lb3 boolean;
  --
  lr_token  token[];
  lt_tokens token[];
begin
  select * p_post_token('', lr_token, lt_tokens)
    into lr_token, lt_tokens, lb1, lb2, lb3;
end$$;
```

I hope this helps others that are struggling with the same.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is not any possibility to do what you requests with one statement. This limit is due some older implementation and cannot be changed because PostgreSQL developers should not want to break compatibility. The workaround with record type is one possible.